# Login issue while running selenium automation script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Whenever i am going to a website and try to log in the application through selenium automation it will get stuck over there.Afterwar when I am increasing Thread.sleep it will again start running But after running it 2 to 3 times again it will stick on login page. how i can resolve that issue?.

I am expecting whenever I will going to run the script it will run smoothly without any intruption

Comment: Provide mode details like your code trials and URL of the website if it is public

Comment: Add your code here, and also try to use wait instead of Thread.sleep
That might help.